# Codeigniter password_verify method

Tags: codeigniter, passwords, verify

I have this   method in my Codeigniter (version 3.0) login module. It works fine but is this safe? Is any better solution to check login and password using PHP password_verify?
(PHP 5.6,
MySQL 5.0).

```
        $user = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');
        $myquery = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user = '$user'");
        $row = $myquery->row();

        if (isset($row))
        {
            //Using hashed password - PASSWORD_BCRYPT method - from database
            $hash = $row->password;


            if (password_verify($password, $hash)) {

                echo 'Password is valid!';


            } else {

                echo 'Invalid password.';

            }


        } else{

            echo 'Wrong user!';
        }
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this **is** the PHP function `password_verify()`, and this function is safe and recommended to use. Even more important is how the hashes are generated, but I guess that the function `password_hash()` is called.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your code looks fine but you can do it a bit more in a CI Way and a bit more cleaner, in this case you are protected by sql injections and you have a bit more encapsulation

Try something like this:

```
public function checkLogin()
{
    $this->load->library("form_validation");

    $arrLoginRules = array
    (
        array(
            "field" => "username",
            "label" => "Benutzername",
            "rules" => "trim|required"
        ),
        array(
            "field" => "password",
            "label" => "Passwort",
            "rules" => "trim|required"
        )

    );

    $this->form_validation->set_rules($arrLoginRules);

    try
    {
        if (!$this->form_validation->run()) throw new UnexpectedValueException(validation_errors());

        $user = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');
        $query = $this->db
            ->select("*")
            ->from("users")
            ->where("user", $user)
            ->get();

        if ($query->num_rows() != 1)    throw new UnexpectedValueException("Wrong user!");

        $row = $query->row();
        if (!password_verify($password, $row->hash)) throw new UnexpectedValueException("Invalid password!");

        echo "valid user";

    }
    catch(Excecption $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Fore more information, take a look at the [Form validation](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html)
and the [Query Builder](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=query%20builder) documentation.

Comment: Thanks for advice.

Comment: what about CI 4? its not working